# Relationship between Sigmoid and Gaussing Distribution

Tags: neural-network, activation-function, gaussian

I was reading this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-neural-networks-from-neuron-to-rnn-cnn-and-deep-learning-cd88e90e0a90) where I came across the following statement in the context of "Why do we use sigmoid activation function in Neural Nets?":

***The assumption of a dependent variable to follow a sigmoid function inherently assumes a Gaussian distribution for the independent variable which is a general distribution we see for a lot of randomly occurring events and this is a good generic distribution to start with.***

Could someone elaborate on this relationship between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure, the core idea is that the sigmoid function approximate very nicely the cumulative density function of a Gaussian distribution. Therefore, if the input of a neuron is a continuous Gaussian distribution, the probability of the output being inferior to a certain value will follow (almost) the shape of the sigmoid function.

A detailed explanation can be found p16 of the following article:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220233479_Catastrophic_Forgetting_and_the_Pseudorehearsal_Solution_in_Hopfield-type_Networks